# What happens when nextUntil() or prevUntil() are called on an HTML string?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand what is going on when `nextUntil()` or `prevUntil()` method is called on an HTML string. I've created a couple of examples to illustrate my point:

```
$('<div></div><p>').nextUntil().length; // why 1?
$('<div></div><div></div><br><p>').nextUntil().length; // why 5?
$('<div></div><div></div><p></p>').nextUntil().length; // why 2?
$('<div></div><!-- comment -->text<div></div>').nextUntil().length; // why 1?
$('<div></div><!-- comment -->text<div></div>').prevUntil().length; // why 1?
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q63y/4/).

Could somebody clarify what is going on when instead of a selector we operate on an HTML string?

Comment: Why are you calling `nextUntil` without any parameters?  What do you expect it do to?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: @RocketHazmat I could call it also with a parameter. nextUntil without parameter should behave as nextAll. I'm more interested in what does nextUntil do with the HTML string.

Comment: Just `console.log()` the results of `.nextUntil()` and look in the console to see what it contains.

Comment: The odd one out is `$('<div></div><div></div><br><p>').nextUntil()`, which returns 5 elements *only* in jQuery 1.9 and 3 elements in jquery 1.8 and 1.10 -- so I'm going to call this an unusual bug.

Comment: If you turn your fiddle to 1.7.2 (the version used here on stackoverflow is 1.7.1, that's how I found this), you'll get 3 instead of 5 for B; So basically what the guy above me said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When called with no parameters, `nextUntil` acts the same as <strike>`next`</strike> `nextAll`.  When you pass an HTML string to jQuery, it makes it into DOM elements.

```
$('<div></div><div></div><br><p>')
```

This creates a jQuery object containing 4 elements.  When you call `nextUntil` on this, it calls it on *each* element.

The 1st element has 3 elements next to it, the 2nd has 2, etc.  That's why you get <strike>6</strike> 5.

Comment: The curiosity is that the first `div` returns 3 elements, the second `div` returns two, and the `br` returns... none? for a total of five.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Ah!  I see.  I was testing with the wrong function when writing my answer.  Let me fix it.

Comment: @Blazemonger: I fixed my explanation.  Wait.  That's 6, not 5.

Comment: @KevinB: Probably because the elements aren't really in the DOM.

Comment: Now: why does `$('<br><p>').nextUntil()` return one element, `p`, while `$('<div></div><br><p>').nextUntil()` returns two, `br` and `p`?

Comment: because in the first, <p> is the only element that is a "next" element, while in the second both the br and the p ar "next" elements.

Comment: @KevinB: The problem is why doesn't `$('<div></div><br><p>').nextUntil()` return 3?  And why doesn't `$('<div></div><div></div><br><p>').nextUntil()` return 6?

Comment: i would expect it to return 5, given the previous trends. Here's a fiddle that shows a little more information: http://jsfiddle.net/6q63y/6/

Comment: @Blazemonger: I figured it out!  I think.  jQuery doesn't, for some reason, like having the same element in the array next to itself.  I think.

Comment: @KevinB: Why should the `$('<div></div><div></div><br><p>').nextUntil()` be 5 and not 6?  `3+2+1` is `6`!  I'm really confused here.  Maybe it's a jQuery bug.

Comment: If you switch to jQuery 1.10, the duplicates are removed and you get three elements instead of five.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Sounds like it was a bug then! :-D

Comment: Another example that confused me is this: `$('<div></div><br><p></p>').nextUntil().length` returns 2 but `$('<div></div><br><br><p></p>').nextUntil().length` returns 5.

Comment: @finspin: It seems like it's a bug in jQuery.  For some reason, it's adding duplicates (which it's not supposed to) to the result.

Comment: that is odd. Though in reality it shouldn't be 5 OR 6, it should be 3. That's solved by making it part of the DOM, http://jsfiddle.net/6q63y/7/ but not by using $.unique. i suspect the issue is $.unique.

Comment: @KevinB: Or by using jQuery 1.10 :-P